# how to output uppercases with regex using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like following:

```
element = ['ABCa4.daf<<tag1>>permission : wiadsfth.accedsafsds.INTERNET<<tag2>>',]
```

I am trying with Regular Expression 'findall' to output only the uppercases at the end of string (before tag2)
Here is what I did:

```
re.findall('<<tag1>>' +"(.*?)"+ '<<tag2>>' , element)
```

but it comes out with other letters before 'INTERNET', give that these letters before INTERNET change all the time, I can't tag them, too.

can anybody sheds a light? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allow any symbols before the `[A-Z]+`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ABCa4.daf<<tag1>>permission : wiadsfth.accedsafsds.INTERNET<<tag2>>'
>>> re.findall('<<tag1>>.*?([A-Z]+)<<tag2>>', s)
['INTERNET']
```

`.*?` is a non-greedy match for any character. `[A-Z]+` matches 1 or more upper case letters.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Just match "any sequence of uppercases, followed by `<<tag2>>`.

```
re.findall(r'[A-Z]+(?=<<tag2>>)', element[0])
```

or

```
re.findall(r'[A-Z]+(?=[^<>]*<<tag2>>)', element[0])
```

to handle stuff like `INTERNET foobar <<tag2>>`.

Finally, to match any sequence of `A-Z` at any position *between* start and end tags, you're going to need this little monster:

```
rr = r"""(?x)
    [A-Z]+
    (?=
        (?:
            (?! <<tag1>>) .
        ) *
        <<tag2>>
    )
"""

element = ['ABC xyz DEF <<tag1>> permission : INTERNET foo XYZ bar <<tag2>>',]
print re.findall(rr, element[0])  # ['INTERNET', 'XYZ']
```